# Finding the posterior with a uniform prior

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

Suppose I have a normal distribution $X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ and I impose a uniform prior on the mean, so that it has to be positive. How do I go about finding the posterior distribution $p(\mu | X_i)$? Following the Bayesian formulas, we would have that $p(\mu | X_i) \propto \text{likelihood}.$ Does this mean that the posterior is the distribution of the normal likelihood? If so, how do I find this distribution?

$\sigma$ is known

Comment: Do you know the value of $\sigma$? If not, you would also need a prior on $\sigma$ to calculate this.

Comment: Yes I do - ill update the question

Comment: The prior is either uniform or strictly positive.

Answer (score 3):

You still need to include the prior density in Bayes' rule; in this case the prior is proportionate to an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) over the range where the mean parameter is positive.  The posterior would be a *truncated* normal distribution:

$$\pi(\mu | \mathbf{x}, \sigma) \propto \text{N}(\mu| \bar{x}, \sigma/n) \cdot \mathbb{I}(\mu > 0).$$

Answer (score 1):

Saying "The distribution of the normal likelihood" is wrong, the normal likelihood is not distributed, what is distributed is $X$ and $\mu$. What you can say is that the posterior has the same form as the likelihood, up to a proportionality constant. Specifically, applying Bayes formula using a uniform prior on $\mu$ between $a$ and $b$ you get $p(\mu|X_i=x,\sigma) = N(x|\mu,\sigma) / \int_a^bN(x|\mu^\prime,\sigma)d\mu^\prime$. Using the limits $a=0$ and $b\to\infty$ that you need, the integral is $\int_0^\infty N(x|\mu^\prime,\sigma)d\mu^\prime = \frac{1}{2}(\textrm{erf}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}\sigma})+1)$. Normally, you don't even need to calculate that integral since it doesn't deppend on $\mu$. You can simply compute the integral of $p(\mu|X_i=x,\sigma)$ numerically and use it to normalize the distribution. Also, for estimating the MAP solution for $\mu$ (which in this case is also the maximum likelihood solution due to the uniform prior) you don't need to know the normalization.